# htaccess help: multiple rules for 301s from same directory

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I don't have a lot of experience with htaccess, but my site is moving to a new domain and I am trying to accomplish the following:

```
Redirect 301 /events/event_x/ http://newsite.com/events/event_x/
Redirect 301 /events/event_y/ http://newsite.com/events/event_y/
Redirect 301 /events/(all other pages in "/events/")/ http://newsite.com/events/
```

basically, I would like all **upcoming events** (event_x and event_y) to **redirect** to their **new urls** on the new domain and all **past/archived** events to **redirect** to the events **homepage** on the new domain.

What's the best way to handle this without having to 301 every page in **"/events/"** individually?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, since the `Redirect` directive symbolically links two paths together, all you really need is:

```
Redirect 301 /events/ http://newsite.com/events/
```

and if someone requests `/events/anything` they'll get redirected to `http://newsite.com/events/anything`, where the "anything" can be anything, including "event_x" or "event_y".

If you wanted, instead, to make `/events/anything` simply redirect to `http://newsite.com/events/` (dropping the "anything" part, then try:

```
Redirect 301 /events/event_x/ http://newsite.com/events/event_x/
Redirect 301 /events/event_y/ http://newsite.com/events/event_y/
RedirectMatch 301 ^/events/ http://newsite.com/events/
```